# How to write into text file what is ordered by years

Tags: c#

I can't order my txt file by nobel[i].year.
The file is in decreasing. I have to do in growing.
I am not genius at at all, so please be simple as possible.

Thanks a lot.

```
struct datas
{
    public int year;
    public string type;
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
}
```

```
datas[] nobel= new datas[923];

using (var sw = new StreamWriter("orvosi.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nobel.Length; i++)
    {
        if (nobel[i].type== "orvosi")
        {
            sw.WriteLine(nobeldij[i].year+ ": " +nobel[i].firstname+" "+nobel[i].lastname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Success! Thanks for help!

Comment: The best way of saying thank you is to mark the answer that helped you as acceptes. If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help

Answer (score 2):

Before your `using` statement put this:

```
nobel = nobel.OrderBy(x => x.year).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that he must add `using System.Linq` at top of the code.

Comment: Success! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you need the sorted array later on, you can also simplify that to the following. Note also the string interpolation `$` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) ) which simplifies the construction of the output string.

```
for (datas n in nobel.OrderBy(x=> x.year)) {
    if (n.type == "orvosi")
        sw.WriteLine($"{n.year}:{n.firstname} {n.lastname}");
}
```

Comment: Success! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) class and some [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.8) extension methods ([`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8), [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8), and [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)), you can shorten your code down to one statement.

- We can use [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8), which writes the contents of an `IEnumerable` to a file (with each item on it's own line).
- We can first filter the data to only those where `type == "orvosi"` using a `Where()` clause.
- Then we can order the filtered items by the `year` property using `OrderBy(data => data.year)`.
- Finally, for each item in the filtered, ordered set, we can `Select` a string (using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)) containing the properties we want to write to the file.

For example:

```
File.WriteAllLines("orvosi.txt", nobel
    .Where(data => data.type == "orvosi")
    .OrderBy(data => data.year)
    .Select(data => $"{data.year}: {data.firstname} {data.lastname}"));
```

Comment: Success! Thanks for help!